# Xcode: More efficient keyboard-based "back" navigation

Tags: xcode, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

In Xcode when we hold the mouse down on the "Back" arrow in the panel above the editor area, we get a popup window showing our navigation history. This is also a standard navigation behavior, seen in most Web browsers.

My question: Is there a keyboard shortcut (or XCode plugin) to pop open this Navigation History popup, so we can use arrow keys and quickly move a selection bar down to the item in the history list we would like to navigate to?

Rationale: When working in a given class, we tend to flip back and forth quite a few times between the `.m` and `.h` files for the class. Each flip creates an entry in the navigation history. So, to move back to the prior *class* we were editing, using keyboard shortcuts only, we need to hit the "go back" keyboard shortcut many times, undoing each flip between header/implementation. Seeing the list visually allows us to quickly identify and scroll down to the desired class in the history list, navigating directly there. When editing code, allowing the hands to remain on the keyboard is better.

Another solution could be: A keyboard shortcut to move back to the previous *class* (or `.xib` or other "significant" navigation item) rather than the previous *file*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a keyboard shortcut (or XCode plugin) to pop open this Navigation History popup

[image: key binding preferences]

**Yes.** The standard key binding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, as indicated above. You can check the key bindings panel in Xcode's preferences for the current key binding on your system if there's any chance that you might have changed it.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. :) I'd gone hunting for this shortcut but couldn't find it.